# RESTEasy POJO json "embedded" objects as links/id's

Tags: java, json, jpa, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a problem with struggling how to represent embedded objects in the POJO as links, instead of embedding them directly.

I'm unsing RESTEasy with the jettison provider. All in 3.0.11.Final version.

The Book.java POJO

```
public class Book
{
    private  Integer bookId;
    private  String title;
    private  Author author;
}
```

The Author.java POJO

```
public class Author
{
    private  Integer authorId;
    private  String name;
}
```

When I use RESTEasy to generate a XML or JSON representation of a book, I see this:

```
<book>
    <bookId>1</bookId>
    <title>My book</title>
    <author>
        <authorId>2</authorId>
        <name>Andre Schild</name>
    </author>
</book>
```

But I wan't to have this:

```
<book>
    <bookId>1</bookId>
    <title>My book</title>
    <author author="2"><atom:link rel="list" href="http://.../rest/authors/2"/></author>
</book>
```

Since we use JPA for the db backend connection, the POJO directly contain the author POJO, and not only the ID.

I also did some tests with jersey, but did also got stuck on the same problem

Answer (score 3):

As nobody knows the relation between the author field and the URI this can't happen automatically. With the plugin reasteasy-links you can define these relations with the two annotations `@AddLinks` and `@LinkResource`. You can find [more information in the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/LinkHeader.html#d4e397).

This plugin does not change the value of the field but will add atom links to the entity. Also it works only with Jettison and JAXB.

Here's a quick + dirty example using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) which really replaces the value of the author field.

We'll use this annotation to define the relation between the POJO and the resource:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Linked {

    String path();

    String rel() default "";

}
```

This annotation needs to be applied to the Author class:

```
@Linked(path = "/rest/authors/{authorId}", rel = "list")
public class Author {}
```

At the Book field we need to add the Serializer we want to use:

```
public class Book {
    @JsonSerialize(using = LinkedSerializer.class)
    private Author author;
}
```

The Serializer could look like this:

```
public class LinkedSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Linked linked = value.getClass().getAnnotation(Linked.class);
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{(.+?)\\}").matcher(linked.path());
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            return;
        }
        String param = matcher.group(1);
        try {
            Field field = value.getClass().getDeclaredField(param);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object paramValue = field.get(value);
            String path = linked.path().replaceFirst("\\{.*\\}", paramValue.toString());
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeFieldName("href");
            jgen.writeString(path);
            jgen.writeFieldName("rel");
            jgen.writeString(linked.rel());
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Note: We're only using a path and not the full URI here as we don't know the base URI and can't inject the UriInfo or ServletRequest in this Serializer. But you could get the ServletRequest via `ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(HttpServletRequest.class)`.

Comment: Just stumbled over resteasy-links and updated my answer.